# Auth0 .NET Core - Reading permissions from access_token

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, access-token, auth0

I'm working with `Auth0` and `.NET Core Web Api` is my server.

On server I've created few endpoints and user has to be authorized to access those endpoints. And that works fine.

I receive `access_token` from `Auth0` and I can invoke methods on web api and that's perfect!

Now I would like to read permission (in .net core) from my `access_token` and in case there is corresponding permission in `access_token` I should access that `endpoint`:

When I decode token using https://jwt.io/ I can see there are permission in a token:

[image]

In my Controller above Endpoint I did next:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize("create:authors")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] UserRequestDto request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await authorsServiceLayer.AddNewAuthor(request, cancellationToken);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

I red a lot of documentation from `Auth0`  but I'm still confused, anyway I added this to my `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = $"https://{_config["Auth0Settings:Domain"]}/";
    options.Audience = _config["Auth0Settings:Audience"];
});

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("create:authors", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("create:authors", $"https://{_config}["Auth0Settings:Domain"]}/")));
});
```

I've no idea what this code in `Startup.cs` is doing.

Anyway what I get when I try to execute this (using this access_token which contains permission) with an postman, I get as a reponse:

> 403 Forbidden

So obliviously I've set up something but I don't know why it's forbidden if I have that permission in a `access_token`??

And by the way should I `options.AddPolicy(..` for each permission that I have in my system?

That sounds like bad solution to me :S

Any kind of help would be awesome!

Cheers

Comment: Just checking in your startup Configure method you also have       app.UseAuthentication();

Comment: You can add `options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents(); options.Events.OnForbidden = n => { return Task.CompletedTask; };` inside your AddJwtBearer() and add a breakpoint or log to see what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explore the Claims with a PermissionHandler all your code is right, but you need to add

A class that implements the interface **IAuthorizationRequirement**

```
public class HasPermissionRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string Issuer { get; }
    public string Permission { get; }

    public HasPermissionRequirement(string permission, string issuer)
    {
        Permission = permission ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(permission));
        Issuer = issuer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(issuer));
    }
}
```

And then add your AuthorizationHandler

```
public class HasPermissionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasPermissionRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasPermissionRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "permissions" && c.Issuer == requirement.Issuer))
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        var permissions = context.User.FindAll(c => c.Type == "permissions" && c.Issuer == requirement.Issuer);

        if(permissions.Any(s => s.Value == requirement.Permission))
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And finally in your **Startup** class inside the method **ConfigureServices** inject your Custom handler

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasPermissionHandler>();
```